# Dynamic allocation with template

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic, dynamic-memory-allocation

I create a class `Vector` that contain two variables that are template variable, I am trying to build such a dictionary that tell mark of a specific student.
The problem is I am struggling dynamic allocating memory with template. I have to do this **without map or STL help.** Can you explain, how to allocate them properly.

```
#define DEF_CAPACITY 20
template <class U, class T>
class Vector {
protected:
    T* _data;
    U* _keys;
    int _size; //size in use
    int _capacity; //available capacity
public:
    //constructors
    Vector(int capacity = DEF_CAPACITY);
    ~Vector();
    int getSize() const { return size; }
    void insert(U key, T data);
    T operator[](U key);
};

template<class U, class T>
inline Vector<U, T>::Vector(int capacity)
{
    this->_capacity = capacity;
    this->_size = 0;
}

template<class U, class T>
Vector<U, T>::~Vector()
{
    if (_data)
        delete[] _data;
    if (_keys)
        delete[] _keys;
}

template<class U, class T>
void Vector<U, T>::insert(U key, T data)
{
    _keys[_size] = new U;
    //Maybe I have to do something like that, but all options I test doesn't work
    //keys[_size] = new U[Some size];
    _keys[_size] = key;

    _data[_size] = new T;
    _data[_size] = data;

    _size++;
}

template<class U, class T>
T Vector<U, T>::operator[](U key)
{
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    if (_keys[i] == key)
        index = i;
return _data[index];
}



int main() {
    Vector<string, int> grades;
    grades.insert("john", 90);
    grades.insert("marc", 100);
    grades.insert("ron", 87);
    grades.insert("lynda", 95);
    //...
    grades.insert("Tome", 93);
    //...
    cout << grades["marc"] << endl;
    cout << grades["lynda"] << endl;
    cout << grades["john"] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about `std::vector<std::pair<Key, Value>>` or just `std::map<Key, Value>`?

Comment: @Jarod42 If you have a solution that can solve the problem without STL help

Comment: If you cannot use std (which seems strange as you use `std::string`), create your own Vector and Pair class (or your binary tree).

Comment: See [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: Is this an assigned project ?  Because `std::map<std::string, int>` is the answer.

Comment: It's no problem if this is a assignment (as you have already put in sufficient effort get help).  It's just nice to know what the limits of any answer are before we work on answers that are not acceptable.

Comment: btw. why would you call that class `Vector` instead of `Map`?

Comment: @StefanRiedel This is the way they call it in my homework. Can you help me solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allocate `n` elements of type `T` you use:

```
T* array = new T[n];
```

so to allocate space for your keys and values:

```
// be aware: this will call the constructor for each element!!!
_keys = new U[n];
_data = new T[n];
```

If your "Vector" has a fixed capacity, this should be done in your constructor:

```
template<class U, class T>
inline Vector<U, T>::Vector(int capacity)
    : _data(new T[capacity]);
    , _keys(new U[capacity]);
    , _size(0);
    , _capacity(capacity);
{
}
```

after that, you can insert key/value pairs like this:

```
template<class U, class T>
void Vector<U, T>::insert(const U& key, const T& data)
{
    if(_size == _capacity)
        throw std::out_of_range("no space left!!!");
    _keys[_size] = key; // copy assignment
    _data[_size] = data; // copy assignment

    _size++;
}
```

This design will unnecessarily call constructors for unused keys and values.

You could also do this with `malloc` and `free` to prevent this, though I wouldn't recommend going that way and instead use the standard library.

Comment: Thanks. When you say `copy assignment` this is assignment operator or something else? Moreover what it's wrong in my operator overloading `[]` that cause that code won't compile

Comment: Yes that's one of the assignment operators. And the problem with your operator[] is that you use `size` instead of `_size` but your compiler should tell you that. If this answers your question, remember to mark it as the accepted anwser.

Comment: just some other tips: 1. your `.insert(...)` should check if an entry with that key already exists and either update that already exsting entry or throw an exception (or change the return value to `bool` and `return false` in that case). 2. your `operator[]` should throw an exception if given key was not found (instead of returning the first data element)